# jQuery action on HTML Checkbox

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I am having a little bit of trouble understanding why my checkbox is not producing any action. I would appreciate any suggestion as to where my mistake occurred.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
<form>
 <div id = "canada1"> <input type ="checkbox" name ="location" value ="canada"> Canada <br><div>
    <div id = "central_america1"> <input type ="checkbox" name ="location" value ="central_america"> Central America <br></div>
</form>

<script type = "text/javascript" src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

<script type = "text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function(){
  alert("this appears")

  $('#canada1').click(function() {

   if ($('#canada1').is(':checked')) {
    alert("Canada is checked");
    console.log("is this working?")
   };

  });
 });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `if ($('#canada1').is(':checked'))` How can a div be checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It because you attach an event on `div`,not the checkbox itself then `:checked` is not applied to it. See code below, and test code snippet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <div id="canada1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="location" value="canada">Canada
      <br>
      <div>
        <div id="central_america1">
          <input type="checkbox" name="location" value="central_america">Central America
          <br>
        </div>
  </form>

  <script type="text/javascript" src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      alert("this appears")

      $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {

        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
          var myVal = $(this).val();
          alert(myVal + " is checked");
          console.log("is this working?")
        };

      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation! I am really new to jQuery and your help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

div element doesn't contain property as 'checked', it is property of checkbox.
`if ($('#canada1').is(':checked'))`

So, in your case, if you pass id='canada1' to checkbox and remove id from div, then your code will work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <div id="canada1Div">
      <input id="canada1" type="checkbox" name="location" value="canada">Canada
      <br>
      <div>
        <div id="central_america1Div">
          <input id="central_america1" type="checkbox" name="location" value="central_america">Central America
          <br>
        </div>
  </form>

  <script type="text/javascript" src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
  alert("this appears")
  $('#canada1').click(function() {
   if ($('#canada1').is(':checked')) {
    alert("Canada is checked");
    console.log("is this working?")
   };

  });
 });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! This was really helpful! :)